# Access 1D array with array of lists or arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 1D array of labels. Object with index i has label label[i]. I also have an array of arrays or lists in which I have indices of labels I would like to access.
For example:

```
labels = np.array([2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
duplicates = np.array(np.array([0,3]), np.array([3,0]), np.array([6,7,8]))
```

I would like to access elements of labels, so the output would look something like this:

```
labels_duplicates = np.array(np.array([2,3]), np.array([3,2]), np.array([0,0,0]))
```

What would be best way to achieve this (preferably without for loops)?

What I would like to achieve: I have an array of center indexes (duplicates). I have to check if labels of those centers match. If they do, centers will be merged into one center. If there is a better solution than the one above, I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets focus on just doing (don't worry about 'loops'):

```
In [82]: duplicates = [np.array([0,3]), np.array([3,0]), np.array([6,7,8])]

In [83]: [labels[x] for x in duplicates]
Out[83]: [array([2, 3]), array([3, 2]), array([0, 0, 0])]
```

I made `duplicates` a list, not an array.  A 1d array of dtype object is little more than a list. (but either works here)

(`np.concatenate(duplicates)` solution moved to end)

As long as your `duplicates` elements differ in length, there isn't a way (that I can think of) that avoids 'loops', iteration over those elements.  That's just the nature of `numpy` indexing.  2d operations are inherently 'rectangular'.  If there is a function that does it directly, it probably is hiding a loop.

---

If only a few `duplicates` are longer, and you don't mind loosing the 'extra' values, you could clip them:

```
labels[np.array([x[:2] for x in duplicates])]

array([[2, 3],
       [3, 2],
       [0, 0]])
```

Similarly you could expand each `duplicate` to the same length.  There's a general purpose `np.pad` function, but it may offer more options than you need.

For padding, the target length requires a comprehension, as the padding itself.  `np.pad` could be used to replicate the last value.  An alternative would be some default or dummy index (e.g. `0`).

```
mlen = max([len(x) for x in duplicates])
padded_dups = [np.pad(x,(0,mlen-len(x)),'edge') for x in duplicates]
labels[np.array(padded_dup)]

array([[2, 3, 3],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

---

Should `duplicates` be a list or object array?  Probably doesn't matter much.

```
[labels[x] for x in np.array(duplicates)]
```

works.  And as you note, `np.array(duplicates)-1` works, where as `[x-1 for x in duplicates]` is required for a list.

In preliminary timings, both subtractions take about the same time, implying that the object array subtraction is performing the equivalent of a list comprehension.

An array like this behaves sometimes like a list, and in other cases like a 2d array.  This an area of development, so you have to try things case by case.

```
array([array([0, 3]), array([3, 0]), array([6, 7, 8])], dtype=object)
```

---

Earlier I showed that you could easily get a flat list of the labels:

```
flat_labels = labels[np.concatenate(duplicates)]
# array([2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

I just realized that `np.split` easily splits such a array into the subarrays that you want:

```
split_indices = np.cumsum([len(x) for x in duplicates])[:-1]
np.split(flat_labels,split_indices)

# [array([2, 3]), array([3, 2]), array([0, 0, 0])]
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing this with list comprehension, but just wanted to know if there are any other options.
Usually elements of duplicates don't differ in length, but I want to make a general solution to also cover the edge cases where they do.
duplicates are generated within a loop, I wanted to know, if labels can be accessed without a loop.  At first duplicates is a list (appending elements), which is than converted to array so I can subtract -1 (if I'm not mistaken it's not possible to subtract from list). Does this mean I'll have to convert duplicates back to a list? Thanks.

Comment: I have one more question. After I have my output of labels, I have to check if elements of any arrays have same labels. Because there are only for possible labels (0 - 3), I use for loop: merge_centers_idx = duplicates[np.where(np.sum(label_duplicates == i, 1) > 1)]. Then I proceed to merging centers with label i.

Comment: I added some notes in response to your first question.  I don't follow the second.

Comment: I can't use clipping since this would mean loss of information. What would be the fastest way for padding (as you said np.pad offers more than I need). How can I know to what size should I pad (what is the max length of list/array inside my array)?

Comment: I expanded on padding.  BUT I think I found a better answer - concatenate the duplicates, index, and then SPLIT the result into subarrays.

Comment: The method with list comprehension is almost twice as fast as method with np.split(). Thanks anyways, your answers are always very helpful.